# How to make regex with number in Mongodb

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I have data as below.

```
[
  { num: 123, name: 'good'},
  { num: 12345, name: 'hey'},
  { num: 4523, name: 'yo' },
  { num: 777, name: 'hihi' }
]
```

And I want to search using regex to get some result.
For example, when I put 45, this search only 12345, 4523.

```
a.find({num: {$regex: req.query.q}, name: 'yo'})
```

But when I pass query like '45', it says "Can't use $regex with Number.".
How can I search using regex with number? Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex can match only when the field being matched has a stirng value, but num in your case is a number.

It says so in the Mongodb docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex

However, there is a workaround using "$where" in which you can execute Javascript to return a boolean.

```
db.collection.find({
  $where: "/45/.test(this.num) && this.name==='yo'"
})
```

I tried it on mongoplayground. 
Try it out: https://mongoplayground.net/p/8E9kGt5moAO

To know more about how $where works, you can see the Mongodb Docs here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/#where

There is also a way to do this without $where (in MongoDb 4.2):

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $and: [
      {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: {
            $toString: "$num"
          },
          regex: "45"
        }
      },
      {
        $gte: [
          "$time",
          12350
        ]
      },
      {
        $lt: [
          "$time",
          12400
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. But I have one more question. I want to add 'name' field more. I edited my question. How can I use multiple condition with where? And I'm using mongoose.
And othere question is what implys 'test' in your case?

Comment: Edited the answer. 'test' is a function in the RegExp prototype in Javascript, so here you would use it just as you use it in JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test
Just ensure the the expression in the $where string results in a boolean

Comment: {orderTime: {
      $gte: `${req.query.from}T00:00:00`,
      $lte: `${req.query.to}T23:59:59.000`
    },
    status: { $nin: ['cancel'] }}

If i have more condition with find. How can I add this conditions inside of your $where?

Comment: I have edited the mongoplayground a bit: https://mongoplayground.net/p/zGNJlsTkaHx
Notice that I've also edited the data a bit where there are two documents with '45' in them and with name 'yo', but one of them is getting filtered out due to time.

Comment: I have one more question. Can't I use your condition with 'countDocument' of mongoose or mongodB? I got error "$where is not allowed in this context"

Comment: I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work with the `countDocuments` function in the Node.js mongodb driver (https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Collection.html#countDocuments). Although I'm not sure about Mongoose because I've never used it before.

Comment: It says use '$expr' instead. But when I use $expr doesn't work samely. Could you help me about this problem?

Comment: Hmm... strange. Try using a query like one at https://mongoplayground.net/p/i4ivmtVJYyn but in countDocuments instead of find (mongoplayground only supports find and aggregate)

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vv83HgkrLs8
check this please. Can you use $expr instead of $where for same result? It's bcz mogndo says that use $expr with countDocuments.

Comment: $expr needs a boolean, so if you supply a string, it's going to take it as true (since string is truthy value) and therefore it's getting all the documents, so the above query will not work. However, I did research and found a solution that does not involve $where: https://mongoplayground.net/p/1FoygvypGTZ

Comment: Really Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Anuj. I have one more question. In my case, I have to migrate mongo from 4.2 to 4.0. So I can't use regexMatch. Could you recommend other way for mongo 4.0?

Comment: Well, I found a solution using an aggregation query, not find: https://mongoplayground.net/p/z7Mu_r4dkoY
Will try to do it with find somehow. Notice I am still using $toString which is supported by mongodb 4.0 so if you go any lower than that then it won't work.